# Vim Back Reference Search and Replace

Tags: search, vim, replace, backreference

I am trying to remove multiple comment lines into single comment lines.

**Before**

```
;
; Comments here
;
```

**After**

```
; Comment here
```

I tried using the following, and it finds all the instances.

```
:%s/\v;$\_s.*;\_s.*\_s+;$/;/gc
```

[image]

But when I try to use `backreference` to get the second line using `\2` it does not work. Here is what I have tried.

```
:%s/\v\(;$\_s.*\)\(;\_s.*\)\(\_s+;$\)/\2/gc
```

My regular expression knowledge is limited, as you can see from above. Please help.

Comment: You're using the 'very-magic' mode (`\v`). You don't need to escape the parenthesis to capture something (escaping a parenthesis in very magic mode actually matches the actual symbol). Change the `\(` and `\)` to `(` and `)` and your command works fine.

Comment: @Marth post that as an answer

Comment: @Marth....that is brilliant....Vim continues to amaze me...Thank you.